# Chrome can only appear on the taskbar after installing .net framework 4.8.1

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, google-chrome

Due to the needs of the project, I installed .net framework4.8.1 in Windows10 to prepare my C# project and set the target framework of the project to 4.8.1 in Visual Studio 2022.

But then there is a strange phenomenon, that is, when I open Chrome, Chrome will be displayed on the taskbar, but it is not displayed on the screen (Of course, this may be other reasons, but I just remember that I did it before it failed. such an operation).

I did a reinstall of Chrome and have tried both x64 and x86

Has anyone encountered a similar situation?

Comment: how are you opening chrome?

Comment: Open the chrome exe directly, and the task manager has shown that chrome is running, but the chrome page cannot be seen

Comment: Hello, may I ask if you used screen expansion or zoomed out the Chrome page to a certain corner before you discovered this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reminder, it is indeed what you guessed

Comment: @Oac Hi, I posted my comment as an answer. You can mark it so that you can help more people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that when you were using Chrome before, Chrome was zoomed out and placed in the corner of the screen. It may also be that when using the screen extension, it is placed on another screen and it is not dragged back